# not able to install ffmpeg php

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, centos, ffmpeg-php

i have installed this ffmpeg in centos server using ffmpeg auto installer

ffmpeg version N-80962-g70d418c

after that i downloaded ffmpeg-php and tried to configure and i got error

**configure: error: ffmpeg headers not found. Make sure ffmpeg is compiled as shared libraries using the --enable-shared option**

some say ffmpeg is not supported in new version php anymore..

but some peoples are using it.. i need to know how they using it now days

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It's a CentOS support question, which is off-topic here.

Comment: i dont know if it is cent os issue... are you saying cent os is the issue here?

Comment: I'm saying that it looks like you're just trying to install software. This question might be better at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Which PHP wrapper for FFmpeg are you referring to? There are 3, but two are long dead.

Comment: ffmpeg-php-0.6.2 this one

Comment: That hasn't been updated for 8 years. You're wasting your time with that. How would it work with a modern FFmpeg? See [FFmpeg Wiki: PHP](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP) and the [php-ffmpeg tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php-ffmpeg/info).

Comment: @Lord which library shall i use then?

Comment: See the links I provided.